# Use residue theorem to calculate the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{1/2}}{1+x^2} dx$

Tags: contour-integration, residue-calculus

I'm working through Boas Chapter 14, and I came across an interesting issue in problem 33.

I get a value for the integral $I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{1/2}}{1+x^2} dx = \frac{i\pi\sqrt{2}}{2}$.  While the answer in the book (and elsewhere online including this website) has no $i$ component, and everything works just fine.

This question has been asked before: [Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{1/2}}{1 + x^2}\,\mathrm dx$ using Residue Theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453109/evaluate-int-0-infty-fracx1-21-x2-mathrm-dx-using-residue-t) but the answer on that question from 2013 has an error in the calculation of the Residue at $-i$.

Specifically, the answer claims

$$
\text{Res}_{-i} \frac{\sqrt{z}}{z^2+1} = \frac{\sqrt{-i}}{-2i} = \frac{-1+i}{-2i\sqrt{2}} = \frac{1-i}{2i\sqrt{2}}
$$
However
$$
\sqrt{-i} = (e^{-i\pi/2})^{1/2} = e^{-i\pi/4} = \cos{\frac{\pi}{4}} - i\sin{\frac{\pi}{4}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
Thus
$$
\frac{\sqrt{-i}}{-2i} = \frac{1-i}{-2i\sqrt{2}} = \frac{-1+i}{2i\sqrt{2}}
$$

With this correction, the sum of the residues is $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, and therefore the value of the contour integral $i\pi\sqrt{2}$.

If you carry out the rest of the contour integration, you pick up the $1/2$ term, and end up with $I = \frac{i\pi\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Am I missing something here?  I saw elsewhere online people mistakenly calculating the Residue at $-i$, is there another way to lose this imaginary component of the answer?

EDIT:

My friend pointed out my error - incase anyone else makes the same mistake as me.

The polar angle must be measured in the positive direction.  Meaning

$$
-i = e^{3\pi/2} \qquad \text{and not}\qquad  -i=e^{-\pi/2}
$$

Then, when you apply the square root, you end up with

$$
-i = e^{3\pi/4} = \frac{-1 + i}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

Which eliminates the imaginary component in the sum of the residues, and therefore in the final answer.

Comment: $\displaystyle\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg)^{2}=\bigg(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg)^{2} = -i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using the wrong branch for the square root. We have $-i=e^{3\pi i/2}$; note that because of how this integral is being calculated (using a "pacman contour" with pacman's mouth along the non-negative real axis), in the residue calculus we should use the branch where the argument lies between $0$ and $2\pi$. So,
\begin{align}
\text{Res}\left(\frac{\sqrt{z}}{z^2+1};-i\right) = \frac{\sqrt{-i}}{-2i}=\frac{e^{3\pi i/4}}{2e^{3\pi i /2}} = \frac{e^{-3\pi i/4}}{2}=\frac{-e^{i\pi/4}}{2}=\frac{-1-i}{2\sqrt{2}},
\end{align}
which is the same thing as $\frac{1-i}{2i\sqrt{2}}$ as in the other answer.

Comment: Yes this was exactly it, I was measuring the polar angle incorrectly.  I updated my post as well.  Thank you